# How to configure kohana database file

Tags: php, database, database-connection, kohana, sqlconnection

I am trying to setup a kohana project on my system. However it complains that its not getting access to database.

```
Database_Exception [ 0 ]: [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'kohana'
```

I have setup the right username and password in the `application/config/database.php` as below:

```
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'database'   => 'database_name',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'password',
```

and in the alternate section too I have changed.

```
        'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'password',
        'persistent' => FALSE,
```

I have setup my `base_url` too at `application/bootstrap.php`

Comment: you should not be using the root user for things like this. always set up a limited privileges account for such things.

Comment: Are you sure the format of the config file matches the expected format? See https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.3/master/config/database.php

Comment: @MarcB Its just a localhost only project.

Comment: @badsyntax Yes its the same way

Comment: have tried to to edit configs in `\database\config` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `modules/database/config/database.php` file solved the problem.

Thanks @Linas